# Showing sorting performance with line graph, not bar graph

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to analysis merge-sort sorting performance in line graph, but still bar graph is showing, how can I implement the graph in line graph? 
 I'm using for-loop increase by 100, so merge sort can sort data, increase by 100. I already make random 10000 size of list in L.

```
Tx = [0] * len(L) # time list

for i in range(0,len(L), 100):
    start_time = time()
    merge_sort(L[:i])
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    Tx[i] = elapsed_time * 1000

plt.plot(Tx, label='merge_sort')

plt.xlim(100, 10000)
plt.ylim(1, 10000)
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Pls give the output of the list `Tx`

Comment: It looks like ```[0.0019073486328125,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,``` this...

Comment: U need to remove `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` as you are taking log on yscale

Comment: I did it...but it still showing bar graph...

Comment: Not to me ..something is wrong in your data or calculation

Comment: sorry about I didn't answer to your answer, I posted partial of the list, not all, actually, Tx size is 10000, so your answer doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is following as explained:

- You have a single non-zero value in your `Tx`. Rest all the values are zero, for which log is not defined. So things look good on a linear scale, but when you plot things on logarithmic y-scale, the only peak appears for non-zero value as it is connected to `-inf` which is the value of log(0). As a result, it looks like a bar to you.

To convince yourself, you can just plot a marker instead of a line using

```
plt.plot(Tx, 'bo', label='merge_sort')
```

[image]

---

**Linear y-scale**

```
Tx = [0.0019073486328125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

plt.plot(Tx, label='merge_sort')
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Logarithmic y-scale**

```
Tx = [0.0019073486328125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

plt.plot(Tx, label='merge_sort')
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Does this works for you?

```
Tx = [0] * len(L) # time list

for i in range(0,len(L), 100):
    start_time = time()
    merge_sort(L[:i])
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    Tx[i] = elapsed_time * 1000

plt.plot(Tx, '-', label='merge_sort')

plt.xlim(100, 10000)
plt.ylim(1, 10000)
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")

plt.show()
```

With the additional arguement in Plot it should force it to plot a line.

Comment: This throws an error. SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: try it again please, post is edited now, haven't compiled it myself due missing data

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import sorting
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr=[]
time_array=[]
x_axis=[]

for i in range(0,1000):
    start_time = time.time()
    arr.append(random.randint(1,10000))
    k=arr.copy()
    sorting.mergeSort(k)
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    time_array.append(elapsed_time * 1000)

print(time_array)

for i in range(0,1000):
    x_axis.append(i)

plt.plot(x_axis, time_array)

# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('no of items')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('time taken by mergesort')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Mergesort graph')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

TRY MY CODE PLEASE.
[image]

i will add picture of 10000 items, when my computer finishes processing.
[image]
you can do pip install sorting   if you don't have.